# How to perform simple collision detection?

Tags: collision-detection, geometry

Imagine two squares sitting side by side, both level with the ground like so:

[image: two squares side by side]

A simple way to detect if one is hitting the other is to compare the location of each side. They are touching if all of the following are false:

- The right square's left side is to the right of the left square's
  right side.
- The right square's right side is to the left of the
  left square's left side.
- The right square's bottom side is above
  the left square's top side.
- The right square's top side is below
  the left square's bottom side.

If any of those are true, the squares are not touching.
But consider a case like this, where one square is at a 45 degree angle:

[image]

Is there an equally simple way to determine if those squares are touching?

Comment: What language are you using? if the squares are images and you use canvas, you could make a simple-ish function detecting the pixel to pixel position.

Comment: You shouldn't do pixel collision detection.  It's far too slow compared to more elegant algorithms like SAT.

Comment: @hustlerinc I'm using C++. The squares will be bitmaps drawn using Direct2D. I don't know what you mean by "use canvas".

Comment: @ktodisco I'm storing the coordinates of each square so it's just an if statement with up to four comparisons between floats. That is slower than the SAT?

Comment: @Rob your extension assumes that one square is always axis-aligned.  It will not work if both squares are rotated.

Comment: @Rob & Ktodisc, What ktodisco says it true. And, even with one cube axis aligned it would still not work. Consider this non collision that would return a collision unless you fully implement SAT: https://public.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pBQQMhFCiAua53FcgEqZDsC7Ko2Ew-tdgCWBbHlh5jQXK9oj079gWeTsIt6Av2KTzYnrN1RN-mbh5gGY1Vbso1w/SATisBetter.jpg?psid=1

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is called the Separating Axis Theorem.  A tutorial of it can be found [here](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html).

Essentially what you want to do, in the case of Object Oriented Bounding Boxes (rotated squares) is project the half-vectors of those squares, let's say 'up' and 'right,' onto the axes in the coordinate spaces of each square.  You also project the vector between the square centers on these axes.  If, for any axis, the sum of the lengths of the projected half vectors is greater than the length of projected distance between the two squares, then they are not colliding.